# How do I finish Castle's entrance? How do I avoid the homing projectile?

Tags: candy-box

I always get hit by the homing projectile(?) thing when playing through this level. Getting hit by it will put the player character back to the leftmost side of the level, which will mean having to plow through the enemies again.

[image: Castle's entrance]

---

**How do I avoid the homing projectile and beat this quest? Any effective tips, tricks and strategies?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the answers on this page is acceptable, but it is important to remember that by this point in the game you ought to have enchanted your sword. While it is not necessary to do so, it does make this level reasonably easy to beat. However, each sword requires its own technique.

With the Sword of Flames, the extra damage makes it rather quick to finish off opponents. On hard mode with a level 5 sword, I found that I kill all the enemies before the asterisk can hit me. The technique here is to watch your health, drink potions when your health drops low enough. If you are teleported to the beginning, drink a potion so that the countdown timer will run out by the time you reach your next opponent.

With the Sword of Life, I found that on regular mode your life will not drop to the point where you will die. The technique is to weather it out and collect candies (though I found this method of earning money rather slow in the long run, especially when you have the GMOOH potion to get to the cow level). After some time, enemies will stop spawning altogether.

If your health isn't high enough or your sword doesn't heal enough, you can use the health potions to prolong your life, however, this can be costly your fist time around. With this said, the technique most people use is the berserk potion. 5 of them are given to you by the frog for answering his questions. The problem is to once again watch your life. Couple the berserk potion with a healing potion or a fire scroll to minimize your chances of dying.

I should also offer you this caveat, this is the level you receive the armor which will reduce the damage you take. There are only a handful of items in this game, so you don't want to miss an item. If you are in a rush to beat the level, your opponents might not drop the item. I suggest that you first tank the game with potions and teleports until you collect the armor, then try the techniques mentioned above to beat the level.

Finally, I have avoided the Sword of Summoning because I have yet to play with it. However, referencing LessPop_MoreFizz's answer, the summons from fallen enemies help to extend your life and allow you more time to heal. Using berserk potions (assuming you have not yet used them all) seems to be the easiest method to beating the level regardless of which sword you use. However, if you rush through the level, once again, you risk missing the armor. I would use the same techniques used with the sword of life with the sword of summoning. Perhaps coupling the flame scroll with the berserk potion would be the easiest method to beating this level.

Answer (score 11):

So, there are a few things you can do that will make this easier:

First off, you can just brute force the level, by upgrading your sword and HP. Eventually, the timing will line up and you'll make it through. This works particularly well with a Sword of Summoning, and can make the Castle Entrance a fairly effective farming spot for additional candy.

Your second option is to try to speed through. **Seven League Boots** go a long way here, as do **Berserk Potions** if you have any left from the frog or a wish. Between those two, you should be able to outrun the teleport spell and make it to the end. You might also employ a **Flame Scroll** to take out a Knight a bit faster if you're worried about it catching up.

Comment: Upgrading the sword of life doesn't upgrade damage, so this level is a very large problem for sword of life. Tips for that sword specifically?

Answer (score 3):

For me, it seems to work fine if I use a teleport scroll directly before the homing projectile hits me. It gets slower the longer it is on its way, so keeping it "alive" longer makes it much easier for you to run away from it.
Of course you have to watch it, because if you meet the next knight directly beneath the projectile, that's either bad luck, or costs another teleport scroll.

Comment: I don't think it gets slower. It seems to always move 1 char in one of the eight directions. It just happens that characters are more tall than wide, so it gives an illusion of moving faster.

Comment: I was in perfect sync with hitting the projectile and a teleport got me able to finish. Was perfect for farming though :)

Answer (score 1):

I found it most effective, when you get good enough to let it run, to use a cloning potion. You keep getting teleported back, but the clone stays and mops up the knights/guards. I did this just now and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Also, the cloning potion requires 1337 candies per potion, so this semi-instantly becomes worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how I beat it the first time, I just spammed scrolls I think; but I do have a good way to beat it the following times (if you're using it to farm candy).

SPOILER:

> I have found that I don't have to use any healing spells when just sitting there and letting it teleport me to the beginning (I have the horn from Castle's Keep and a Life Sword). The longer you let it run, the more candies you get, and since teleporting you to the beginning helps you recover hp, you always stay at max hp. I'm not sure how long it'll run for if you just run the quest and forget about it, but I did the quest and came back an hour and a half later, and it had stopped (I'm hoping that I beat it, and can't see how I wouldn't have, since I sat there for like 15 minutes before leaving, and I was always back at max hp after being teleported). EDIT: To farm candies like this you need to be under approx 550 hp, because then you can go through and not have the teleporter thing hit you.

Answer (score -1):

Use a Berserk Potion with a Chocolate Coated Diamond Sword. That's what I did and I never got hit.